# Creating bookmarked PDF from Mapbook (Python) export script

Tags: arcpy, export, pdf, data-driven-pages, bookmarks

I regularly use an export script to create multi-page PDFs from Data-Driven-Pages based Map-books.  I am able to export and append each individual page to the PDF, and save the PDF in the single-page layout with the "Page Thumbnails" pane opened.  I need to be able to (Pythonically) set the Bookmark text for each page within the PDF.  I can do this manually from Adobe, but it would save a lot of time and headache if it could be automated.

Here is the script I use, at its most basic level without any bells or whistles.  At the bottom of the script is where I set the page-layout (`pdf_open_view="USE_THUMBS"`).  I can use `"USE_BOOKMARKS"` but this doesn't actually apply any bookmark text to the individual pages.

```
import arcpy, os
mxdPath = r"C:\temp\MyMapBook.mxd" 
tempMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
tempDDP = tempMap.dataDrivenPages

outDir      = r"C:\temp"   #PDF Folder where the individual pages and Combo are created
comboPDF    = r"\MultiPage_PDF.pdf"        #Name of Combo PDF
finalpdf_filename = os.path.join(outDir + comboPDF)
finalPdf = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(finalpdf_filename)

for pgIndex in range(1, tempDDP.pageCount + 1):
    tempDDP.currentPageID = pgIndex
    figName = str(tempDDP.pageRow.sdsFeatureName)
    figNumber = str(tempDDP.pageRow.Fig_Num_2015FSP)
    pageName = "Page-" + figNumber + "_" + figName + ".pdf"
    individualPagePDF = os.path.join(outDir + "\\" + pageName)

    #do something to the page before exporting. e.g. add inset map, add table etc.

    ###################################################################
    tempDDP.exportToPDF(individualPagePDF, "CURRENT") # export to signle page PDF
    finalPdf.appendPages(individualPagePDF) # append the page to the "combo" PDF
    print pageName + " added to final mapbook pdf"                    
    ###################################################################

    #undo whatever page modifications you just did before the export

##### Delete Objects
del tempMap, tempDDP

finalPdf.updateDocProperties(pdf_open_view="USE_THUMBS",pdf_layout="SINGLE_PAGE")
finalPdf.saveAndClose()
```

Comment: I have a similar workflow where I create a multipage PDF map atlas from an MXD with the Data Driven Pages module. I then add PDF metadata, bookmarks and control the page display with a pdfmarks postscript file that is combined with my map atlas using Ghostscript (https://www.ghostscript.com/). Check out the "Embedding PDFmarks" section of this page (http://milan.kupcevic.net/ghostscript-ps-pdf/) for a quick primer. All of this can be scripted fairly easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PyPDF2 module works as needed in this situation.  The script no longer uses `arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate`.  The combo-PDF is now created using the PyPDF2 module.  In the below script, it begins with the `output = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()`.

Because multiple users need to access the module across the office network, installing the module on my machine would not have worked.  Instead, the PyPDF2 module was placed in a network folder, and `sys.path.insert` was added to the script with the location to the network path.

Here is the working script that bookmarks each page within the combo-PDF.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r"H:\NetworkShared_PythonModules") # insert a path to the folder containing the PyPDF2 module
import PyPDF2, os, arcpy

mxdPath = r"C:\temp\MyMapBook.mxd" 
tempMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
tempDDP = tempMap.dataDrivenPages


outDir      = r"C:\temp"   #PDF Folder where the individual pages and Combo will be created
comboPDF    = r"MultiPage_PDF.pdf"        #Name of Combo PDF
finalpdf_filename = os.path.join(outDir, comboPDF)
output = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()

for pgIndex in range(1, tempDDP.pageCount + 1):
      tempDDP.currentPageID = pgIndex
      figName = str(tempDDP.pageRow.sdsFeatureName)
      figNumber = str(tempDDP.pageRow.Fig_Num_2015FSP)
      pageName = "Appendix Page-" + figNumber + "_" + figName + ".pdf"
      individualPagePDF = os.path.join(outDir, pageName)
      bookMarkText = "Figure A-" + figNumber + " --- " + figName

      #do something to the page before exporting.  e.g. add inset map, add table etc.

      ###################################################################
      tempDDP.exportToPDF(individualPagePDF, "CURRENT") # export to signle page PDF
      IndividualPageInput = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(individualPagePDF, 'rb'))
      output.append(IndividualPageInput, bookMarkText)
      print pageName + " added to final mapbook pdf"                    
      ###################################################################

      #undo whatever page modifications you just did before the export

outputStream = file(finalpdf_filename, "wb")
output.setPageLayout("/SinglePage")#open the pdf to single page layout
output.setPageMode("/UseOutlines")#open the pdf with the bookMarks pane open
################################
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
del outputStream, output

##### Delete Objects
del tempMap, tempDDP
```

Comment: Did you see anything that might also help answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121651/writing-hidden-information-to-pdf-file-from-arcmap ?

Comment: You can, in fact, edit a PDFs properties using the PyPDF2 module.  I posted an answer on the link page.

Comment: I've run out of votes for today so when I get my next batch in about 45 mins I'll upvote that answer.  In the meantime I have tweeted it to my followers so hopefully some votes may flow from that.

Answer (score 1):

In the [PDFDocument help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/pdfdocument-class.htm) it makes two mentions of bookmarks:

> USE_BOOKMARKS —Displays the document plus the Bookmarks panel

and

> "DOC_ASSEMBLY" —Grants permission to perform page insert, delete, and
>   rotate, and allows creation of bookmarks and thumbnails

I suspect that the only support for bookmarks is when ArcPy's `appendPages` or `insertPages` methods are used to merge in existing PDF files which have bookmarks embedded within them.

Comment: If it is possible to export the individual pages with their own bookmark text, I would love to try it.  I don't see any mention of this in the arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF documentation.  Currently looking into the PyPDF or PyPDF2 modules.  They appear to hold some promise.  Will post findings here.